# Android 11 : store file on app specific external storage

Tags: android-11, scoped-storage

I wanted to store jpg file to app specific directory in external storage on android 11.  Below code is working fine on emulator but not on google pixel 4a. can someone guide me here.

```
val appDirectory = context.getExternalFilesDir(null)
                appDirectory?.let { dir ->
                    val file = File(dir.absolutePath, "test.jpg")
                    FileOutputStream(file).use {
                        imageFile.bitmap.compress(getBitmapFormat(imageFile.format), 100,it)
                    }
                }
```

Comment: What exactly are your symptoms? How are you looking for this file?

Comment: @CommonsWare I am trying to create a test.jpg file on an external app directory. expected result  - folder with the app name and file name is created in android/data.   Actual result  - no folder is created nor file in the android/data folder.  if same code is run on emulator API 30  both folder and file si getting created.